# How to change content of a modal at each opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have'a modal ( **I use twitter bootstrap 2.3.2** and I need to use it please dont say to use bootstrap3), and I want to show different content based on the clicked button. In other words, there are multiple buttons that are added dynamically into dom, and based on the clicked button, I need to show different content. Currently, it always shows the content of the first clicked button no matter where I'am pushing. Here is my code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> × </button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Query Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

       <div id="graph" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;cursor:default;" class="{{getViewType}}">
           <center id="splash" style="padding-top:230px;">
               <img src="../images/loading.gif">
           </center>
       </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my handler:

```
$(document).on('hidden','#myModal',function(){
    console.log('it comes here');  // this is printed every time I close modal
     $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

Comment: You have to show the content on modal - right? So where is your handler for opening the modal?

Comment: When I click the buttons, modal is opened automatically.  `var question=$("<img src='../images/question_button.png'/>").attr('id',uniqueID+'^^explore').attr('data-toggle',"modal").attr('data-target','#myModal').addClass('explore');` this is how I create buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check that the id's of the dynamically added buttons are unique. Also that any function code that will run when they're clicked, is also dynamically added otherwise it won't run. It would certainly help to see the code for the buttons.

Comment: thank you for reply, I double check the IDs and I'm sure they're unique. Let me make it more clear. Assume there are two buttons(let call them A and B) If I press first A, it shows the content of A correctly, and If I press  B first, then it shows correctly it too. But If I press B after I press A and close the modal, when reopened, it still shows the content of A

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/on5zvj6t/)**

Ok.. I prefer `.shown` event of `modal` for this case and a global variable to store the data of clicked `button` as below

```
var dataToShow=""; //global variable

//A button click event to store data
$('button').on('click',function(){
    dataToShow=$(this).text();//For DEMO purpose am storing text of button clicked in dataToShow
});


$(document).on('shown','#myModal',function(){
    //Will be triggered when modal is opened
    alert(dataToShow);//Just for verification
    $('.modal-body .datadisplay').html(dataToShow); 
    //assign the value in a separate div inside modal-body so that you will not replace anything else each time
});
```

Now since the `button` is dynamically created, I would suggest to use `event delegation` here to attach `event` to `button`

```
$(document).on('click','.yourbuttonClass',function(){
     dataToShow=$(this).text();
});
```

Now if you want you can make use of

```
$(document).on('hidden',"#myModal",function(){
    //clear the contents inside an element added i.e. .datadisplay inside modal-body
    $('.modal-body .datadisplay').empty();   
})
```

Comment: will the last part work on its own or should I apply the top part too ?

Comment: which last part you are talking about? `hidden` event?

Comment: That will automatically call when `modal` is closed. So while opening the `modal` - `shown` event and while closing the `modal` - `hidden` event will be called..